# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null

Tags: javascript, html, bxslider

This weird bug is bugging me from half an hour. I am dynamically trying to apply a slider using only JavaScript. Any idea as to why this is occurring to me? I could find other questions on SO, but could not understand the solution. I am new to JS and highly appreciate if someone could explain me things in laymen terms. Here is my code.

**MARKUP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>JS sample test page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.bxslider.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="og-fullimg"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// code for thumbnail slider begins
(function() {
    var ogImg = document.getElementsByClassName("og-fullimg");
    alert(ogImg.length);
    var bxSlider = document.createElement("ul"); //created ul
    bxSlider.setAttribute("class", "bxslider"); // gave a class name bxslider.

    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        var itemsList = document.createElement("li");
        var linkImages = document.createElement("img");
        linkImages.src = "images/bid_" + i + ".jpg";
        itemsList.appendChild(linkImages);
        bxSlider.appendChild(itemsList);
    }

    ogImg[0].appendChild(bxSlider);
    document.body.appendChild(ogImg); //append everything to the body.


    //call the slider.
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            auto: true,
            pager: false,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            slideWidth: 550
        });
    });

}());
// code for thumbnail slider ends.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message says it all, you're not getting the element.

Comment: Also, you're doing `document.body.appendChild(ogImg);`, but `ogImg` is already in the DOM, why do you need to append it ?

Comment: Just as a quick note `$('div')` will select all divs already in the DOM, while `$('<div/>')` will create a new DOM element that you can insert into the DOM. If you select existing divs, then you can't re-insert them into the DOM. If you try you'll get this error message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several issues here:

1. `document.body.appendChild(ogImg);` is just wrong.  `ogImg` is a `nodeList`.  You can't directly append a `nodeList` to the body AND it's already in the DOM (you just got it with `document.getElementsByClassName("og-fullimg");`.
2. You are using `$(document).ready()` to wait to call .bxSlider(), but NOT using it to call `document.getElementsByClassName()`. My guess would be your code is just running too soon. If that is the case, then just put all your code inside the `.ready()` handler.
3. You're using a very odd mix of plain javascript and jQuery when switching the plain javascript over to jQuery could make your code smaller and more consistent.  If you have jQuery, you may as well use it for what it's good at (which is selectors and operations on collections - among other things).

This is what I'd suggest:

```
//create and initialize the slider.
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bxSlider = $("<ul class='bxslider'></ul>"), img;
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = "images/bid_" + i + ".jpg";
        $("<li>").append(img).appendTo(bxSlider);
    }
    bxSlider.appendTo(".og-fullimg");

    bxSlider.bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        pager: false,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        slideWidth: 550
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, I removed it according to your first suggestion and the slider works now without error(I changed document.body.appendChild(ogImg); to document.body.appendChild(bxSlider);). But I dint quite get your second point. And the whole content is going after "og-fullimg" div. I want it to be inside the div. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ThomasSebastian - I modified the code slightly to insert the newly created bxslider content inside the `og-fullimg` element like you asked.